# StackExchange TimeoutException when trying to insert 750 items in 2 sets in redis

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve, stackexchange.redis

Initially I'm trying to **insert some collection of items into 2 redis sets** (maybe this is not good idea at all, but ...). **amount of entries** that I'm trying to add at once: **750+**

For now I do **receive timeout exception when trying to perform this action using StackExchange.redis** client, the interesting thing that I'm **able to complete similar action using "legacy" booksleeve** client I've investigated previously.

So, I definitely wrong in something (even maybe in my intial bookSleeve implementation), just trying to figure out what exactly is wrong.
Below is sample of the code that I use with redis clients:
**BookSleeve:**

```
using (var tran = connection.CreateTransaction())
{
Task lastOpTask = null;
tran.SuspendFlush();
try
{
    // perform required configurations/ actions
    tran.Sets.Add(_redisConfiguration.DbNumber, CurrentIdsSetDbKey, stringIds);
    tran.Sets.Add(_redisConfiguration.DbNumber, CurrentDetailsSetDbKey, stringDetails);
    lastOpTask = tran.Execute();
    isOperationSuccessful = true;
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    ...
}
catch (TimeoutException ex1)
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    tran.ResumeFlush();
}

if (lastOpTask != null)
{
    connection.Wait(lastOpTask);
    ...
}
}
```

**StackExchange.redis implementation of the same code:**

```
var tran = db.CreateTransaction();

// todo: do we need to add here any condition or PipeLining? any watch/unwatch verifications?
tran.SetAddAsync(CurrentIdsSetDbKey, stringIds);
tran.SetAddAsync(CurrentDetailsSetDbKey, stringDetails);

try
{
    isOperationSuccessful = tran.Execute();
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    ...
}
catch (TimeoutException ex1)
{
    ...
}
```

After I start unit tests I receive next error for StackExchange client:

`Message: Timeout performing EXEC, inst: 3, queue: 3, qu=0, qs=3, qc=0, wr=0/0`

`Source:    in StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\18a91a3757cef937\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1693
   in StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\18a91a3757cef937\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 92
   in StackExchange.Redis.RedisTransaction.Execute(CommandFlags flags) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\18a91a3757cef937\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisTransaction.cs:line 51
   in DFS.Cache.CacheManager.RedisStackExchange.RedisContestCacheManager.RegisterAvailableContests(IList1 contests) in d:\Projects\DFS\Code\DFS\DFS.Cache.CacheManager.RedisStackExchange\RedisContestCacheManager.cs:line 131`

**Just wondering, what exactly I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!.**

P.S. For stackEchange.redis configuration I'm using config sample provided by Marc from github (available here: StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Configuration.md)

P.S. 
Please see current StackExchange client Config file:

```
var config = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    EndPoints =
        {
            {"MasterIP", 6379},
            {"SlaveIP", 6380}
        },
    CommandMap = CommandMap.Create(new HashSet<string>
        {
            // EXCLUDE a few commands (to work with data-flow-related mode only)
            "INFO",
            "CONFIG",
            "CLUSTER",
            "PING",
            "ECHO",
            "CLIENT"
        }, available: false),
    KeepAlive = 60, // 60 sec to ensure connection is alive
    ConnectTimeout = 5000, // 5 sec
    SyncTimeout = 5000, // 5 sec
    ServiceName = "mymaster", // sentinel service name
    DefaultVersion = new Version(2, 8, 8),
    Password = "password"
};
```

Standard entry (used in sets) looks like:

```
{
    "Id":"08e5ffdbced046cb8f55c50e4bab822d",
    "Entries":0,
    "State":"i",
    "Name":"very dummy entry name value: autoGet 299",
    "Summary": "entry summary details, some long string 299, some common info, some data: true, 8200"
    "IsMultiple":true,
    "IsPublic":true,
    "MaxEntries":8200,
    "IsEntryVisible":true,
    "StartDate":"9/10/2014 12:00:00 AM"
}
```

P.S.
After Marc's response I ran couple of tests and got some other errors in Unit tests, 
for example

```
{"Timeout performing SISMEMBER set:raw:Ids, inst: 1, queue: 6, qu=0, qs=6, qc=0, wr=0/0"} when set contains not more than 300 items.
```

**So I agree that this is Connection issue and has nothing to do with current switch to the StackExchange.redis client.**

Comment: I will investigate later

Comment: So that I can investigate properly: what do the two inputs look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following passes just fine, and reports 10ms locally. I would be very interested if you could fill in the blanks a bit so I can do a representative test that reproduces the issue. Note that `qu=0, qs=3` tells me that at the point that it times out, we're waiting for the redis server to respond. Obviously local bandwidth and latency would be of interest, but fundamentally, *it should work*. I'd also be interested in what your sync-timeout is set to.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StackExchange.Redis.Tests.Issues
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SO22786599 : TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Execute()
        {
            string CurrentIdsSetDbKey = Me() + ".x";
            string CurrentDetailsSetDbKey = Me() + ".y";

            RedisValue[] stringIds = Enumerable.Range(1, 750).Select(i => (RedisValue)(i + " id")).ToArray();
            RedisValue[] stringDetails = Enumerable.Range(1, 750).Select(i => (RedisValue)(i + " detail")).ToArray();

            using (var conn = Create())
            {
                var db = conn.GetDatabase();
                var tran = db.CreateTransaction();

                tran.SetAddAsync(CurrentIdsSetDbKey, stringIds);
                tran.SetAddAsync(CurrentDetailsSetDbKey, stringDetails);

                var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var isOperationSuccessful = tran.Execute();
                watch.Stop();
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Assert.IsTrue(isOperationSuccessful);                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't know that comments can be edited only for 5 minutes :). Initial timeouts and sync structure were set to 1500 ms at first (but then I set them to the default 5000ms (as mentioned in the documentation). I think that you're right and it looks like server response issue, as now I'm getting  additional issues with my other unit tests (and similar issues with event smaller collections, starting from 500). I'll try to provide required network information a bit later.

Comment: Hey @marc-gravell, Is there a place where we can find out what the "qu=0, qs=1, qc=0, wr=0/0" means?

Comment: @Steffan and anyone else who many be wondering about what those values mean, see [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/10/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/).

Comment: Sorry for forking you but I am receiving kind a similar issue and it's happening very frequently for past 2days. Have raised a separate question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660545/timeoutexception-exception-in-stackexchange-redis-net-library. Can you suggest some solution/workaround please. Thanks Marc.

Comment: @Steffan This link explains what those codes mean: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/

Comment: @gigi Thanks for that link