# How can i add List of custom object in Redis by range redis List

Tags: c#, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis, .net-4.5.2

Is there any way I can add List of my ojects in redis Stackexchange.Redis.Extensions.
I know i can use SetAdd but it insert items one by one. I wanted to insert in Range.
I also want's retrieve items by Range.
i.e by start and end index
In following code i am able to extract List via chunk but it returns RedisValue[]. How can i convert it into my List

Note

```
  public static List<T> GetListItemRange<T>(string key, int start, int chunksize) where T : class
    {
        List<T> obj = default(List<T>);
        try
        {
            if (Muxer != null && Muxer.IsConnected && Muxer.GetDatabase() != null)
            {
                var cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(Muxer, new NewtonsoftSerializer());
                var values = cacheClient.Database.ListRange(key, start, (start + chunksize - 1));
                obj = Array.ConvertAll(values, x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(x)).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Fatal(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

while list addition part at the moment is

```
public static bool InsertListItemRange<T>(string key, List<T> obj) where T : class
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
                if (Muxer != null && Muxer.IsConnected && Muxer.GetDatabase() != null)
                {
                    var cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(Muxer, new NewtonsoftSerializer());
                    foreach (var o in obj)
                    {
                        result = cacheClient.ListAddToLeft(key, o) > 0;    
                    }                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Fatal(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Did u look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22794163/1876572

Comment: It is adding simple string while i wanted to add List of items of my custom class.

Comment: Now only problem is one by one entry in list. Can some how i can insert my List<T> via bulk insert into Redis List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Code For Insertion of List  into Redis is

```
public static bool InsertListItemRange<T>(string key, List<T> obj, int chunksize = 25000) where T : class
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
                if (Muxer != null && Muxer.IsConnected && Muxer.GetDatabase() != null)
                {
                    var cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(Muxer, new NewtonsoftSerializer());

                    List<RedisValue> lst  = new List<RedisValue>();

                    foreach (var o in obj)
                    {
                       lst.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o));   
                    }


                    result = cacheClient.Database.ListLeftPush(key, lst.ToArray()) > 0;


                    if (LogRedisRelatedActivities)
                    {
                        Logger.InfoFormat("InsertItem => Key: {0}, Result: {1}", key, result);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Fatal(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Also For Fetching Via Range My code is

```
public static List<T> GetListItemRange<T>(string key, int start, int chunksize) where T : class
        {
            List<T> obj = default(List<T>);
            try
            {
                if (Muxer != null && Muxer.IsConnected && Muxer.GetDatabase() != null)
                {
                    var cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(Muxer, new NewtonsoftSerializer());
                    var redisValues = cacheClient.Database.ListRange(key, start, (start + chunksize - 1));
                    if (redisValues.Length > 0)
                    {
                        obj = Array.ConvertAll(redisValues, value => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value)).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Fatal(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

Comment: This is still inserting One by one , seems there is no option to addrange ryt ?

Comment: it is inserting in one go. result = cacheClient.Database.ListLeftPush(key, lst.ToArray()) > 0;

Comment: or it can be in a single line with result = cacheClient.Database.ListLeftPush(key, obj.Select(JsonConvert.SerializeObject).Select(dummy => (RedisValue) dummy).ToArray()) > 0;