# IRedisDatabase ListAddToLeft cannot serialize object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis, asp.net-core-5.0

I am adding entity to DB and trying to add it to redis too.

```
...
_dbContext.MailQueue.Add(mailQueue);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

var response = _redisCoreManager.ListAddToLeft(RedisConstants.MAILQUEUE, mailQueue);
```

`RedisCoreManager.cs` method:

```
public long ListAddToLeft<T>(string key, T value) where T : class
{
    var redisValue = default(long);
    try
    {
        redisValue = redis.ListAddToLeft(this.configParamterKey + key, value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logCoreMan.Error("Redis ListAddToLeft Exception", ex);
    }

    return redisValue;
}
```

And result:

> ��������a@� ������{"Subject": .............

My expectation:

> {"MailQueueId":2218,"EmailTypeId":4,{"Subject": ...............

It looks a serializing problem? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592771/how-can-i-add-list-of-custom-object-in-redis-by-range-redis-list

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad, this(your link) is .net and I also have .net project that is working well. Problem is in my .net core project.