# TimeoutException exception in StackExchange Redis .NET Library

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

We are using `stackexchange.redis.dll` but recently I am seeing lots of below exception in log. Any idea what's getting wrong?

> TimeoutException exception: Timeout performing EXISTS key1234, inst:
>   1, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 10, qu: 0, qs: 10, qc: 0, wr: 0,
>   wq: 0, in: 2304, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=4,Free=996,Min=4,Max=1000),
>   WORKER: (Busy=15,Free=4080,Min=4,Max=4095), clientName: testclient

**Info:**

due to some requirement, I am fetching all existing keys from Redis cache by saying `connectioncontext.Server("host").Keys()` and in `Redis` document somewhere I saw that, fetching keys frequently can lead to decreasing cache performance. But I am fetching the keys only 4 times / day (I mean in application). Will that cause any issue at all?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> Timeout performing SET {Key}, inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, queue: 2, qu=1,
>   qs=1, qc=0, wr=1/1, in=0/0 means, it has sent one request (qs), there
>   is another request that's in unsent queue (qu), while there is nothing
>   to be read from the network. there is an active writer meaning the one
>   unsent is not being ignored. Basically, there is a request sent and
>   waiting for the response to be back.

I fixed it doing the following: I set the connection timeout to 30 seconds,

```
ConnectTimeout = 30000, // 30 seconds
SyncTimeout = 20000, // 20 seconds 
ConnectRetry = 3
```